# mysql select user information and group categories

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a mysql search, which returns user information with grouped categories (group_id's). I just need some help getting my query right:

```
SELECT a.*, a.name AS editor, a.name AS created_by, b.*, c.* FROM `cm0x8_users` AS a LEFT JOIN cm0x8_users_xref AS b ON b.userid = a.id LEFT JOIN cm0x8_user_usergroup_map AS c ON c.user_id = a.id WHERE (a.block IN (0, 1)) AND c.group_id NOT IN(6,7,8) ORDER BY a.name asc
```

Is returning the same user 3 times (they are in 3 different groups).

Example:

```
id          name          group_id
1           Fred          1
1           Fred          2
1           Fred          3
2           John          1
3           Jane          1
3           Jane          3
```

But I'm after:

```
id          name          group_id
1           Fred          1, 2, 3
2           John          1
3           Jane          1, 3
```

(or similar)

Any help would be great!

Comment: Use `CONCAT` & `GROUP BY`.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT may be helpful.

Comment: Seeing as you've tagged this with PHP, just do some simple array processing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be giving me my expected results..

```
SELECT a.*,a.name AS editor,a.name AS created_by,b.*,group_concat(c.group_id) as gid,c.* FROM `#__users` AS a LEFT JOIN #__users_xref AS b ON b.userid = a.id LEFT JOIN #__user_usergroup_map AS c ON c.user_id = a.id WHERE (a.block IN (0, 1)) AND c.group_id NOT IN(6,7,8) GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.name asc
```